# Finding an invariant for a simple loop

Tags: dafny, loop-invariant

I have never felt so woefully inadequate as I am when trying to prove to Dafny that my program is correct, so I need your help: The given program looks as follows:

```
method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
requires N <= M //given precondition
ensures 2*s == M*(M+1)-N*(N+1) //given postcondition
{
    var a: int := N;
    var r: int := 0;

    while a < M 
    invariant FIND ME!
    {
        a := a+1;
        r := r+a;
    }
    return r;
}
```

As first step I wanted to figure out what the loop does, so I made a table:

[image]

With that I worked out a loop invariant for `r`:

```
invariant r == (a-N)*N + (a-N)*((a-N)+1)/2
```

which holds before (`0==0`), and after each iteration of the loop (following the formula). Clearly it does not satisfy the Termination criteria

> When the loop terminates, the loop invariant along with the reason that the loop terminated gives us a useful property.

Since the loop guard is simple enough I figured the complete invariant should be

```
invariant a<=M && r == (a-N)*N + (a-N)*((a-N)+1)/2
```

And thus my invariant satisfies Initialization, Maintenance and Termination. However Dafny complains that

> Error: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.

How do I make Dafny happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to stay clear of any non-linear arithmetic hick-ups. Here's how I think of the problem:

You're trying to establish a postcondition that, for the sake of clarity, I will write as `P(s, N, M)`, that is, some function of `s`, `N`, and `M`. One technique for coming up with a loop that does this is "replace a constant by a variable". What this means is that you pick one of the constants of the desired postcondition (here, you can choose either `N` or `M`, since `s` is not a constant) and replace it by a variable that is going to change in each loop iteration. Let's pick `M` as the constant and let's introduce (as you had already done in your program) `a` as the variable. Since we picked `M` as the constant, we'll want the final value of `a` to be `M`, so we'll start `a` at `N`. We then have:

```
method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
  requires N <= M
  ensures P(s, N, M)
{
  var a := N;

  while a < M
    invariant N <= a <= M
    invariant P(s, N, a)  // postcondition, but with variable a instead of constant M
}
```

If you type in this program (but expand out the `P(s, N, a)` to the actual condition), then you will find that Dafny proves the postcondition. In other words, the verifier is giving you the information that *if* you can establish and maintain this loop invariant, then the program will correctly establish the postcondition.

You can see this yourself, too. The negation of the loop guard gives you `M <= a`, which combined with the loop invariant `a <= M` gives you `a == M`. When you combine `a == M` and the loop invariant `P(s, N, a)`, you get the postcondition `P(s, N, M)`.

Great. But the verifier issues a complaint that the loop invariant does not hold on entry. This is because we didn't provide any initial value for `s`. Since `a` has the initial value `N`, we need to find a value for `s` that satisfies `P(s, N, N)`. That value is `0`, so we update the program to

```
method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
  requires N <= M
  ensures P(s, N, M)
{
  var a := N;
  s := 0;

  while a < M
    invariant N <= a <= M
    invariant P(s, N, a)
}
```

Next, let's write the loop body. (Notice how I have *started* with the loop invariant, rather than starting with loop body and then trying to figure out an invariant. For these sorts of programs, I find that's the easiest way.) We already decided that we want to vary `a` from the initial value `N` up to the final value `M`, so we add the assignment `a := a + 1;`:

```
method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
  requires N <= M
  ensures 2*s == M*(M+1) - N*(N+1)
{
  var a := N;
  s := 0;

  while a < M
    invariant N <= a <= M
    invariant P(s, N, a)
  {
    a := a + 1;
  }
}
```

This addresses termination. The final thing we need to do is update `s` inside the loop so that the invariant is maintained. This is mostly easily done *backward*, in a goal-directed fashion. Here's how: At the end of the loop body, we want to make sure `P(s, N, a)` holds. That means we want the condition `P(s, N, a + 1)` to hold *before* the assignment to `a`. You obtain this condition (again, remember we're working backward) by replacing `a` in the *desired* condition with (the right-hand side of the assignment) `a + 1`.

Okay, so before the assignment to `a`, we want to have `P(s, N, a + 1)`, and what we've got just inside the loop body is the invariant `P(s, N, a)`. Now, it's time for me to expand `P(...)` to your actual condition. Alright, we have

```
2*s == a*(a+1) - N*(N+1)                (*)
```

and we want

```
2*s == (a+1)*(a+2) - N*(N+1)            (**)
```

Let's rewrite `(a+1)*(a+2)` in `(**)` as `2*(a+1) + a*(a+1)`. So, `(**)` can equivalently be written as

```
2*s == 2*(a+1) + a*(a+1) - N*(N+1)      (***)
```

If you compare `(***)` (which is what we want) with `(*)` (which is what we've got), then you notice that the right-hand side of `(***)` is `2*(a+1)` more than the right-hand side of `(*)`. So, we must arrange to increase the left-hand side with the same amount.

If you increase `s` by `a+1`, then the left-hand side `2*s` goes up by `2*(a+1)`, which is what we want. So, our final program is

```
method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
  requires N <= M
  ensures 2*s == M*(M+1) - N*(N+1)
{
  var a := N;
  s := 0;

  while a < M
    invariant N <= a <= M
    invariant 2*s == a*(a+1) - N*(N+1)
  {
    s := s + a + 1;
    a := a + 1;
  }
}
```

If you want, you can swap the order of the assignments to `s` and `a`. This will give you

```
method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
  requires N <= M
  ensures 2*s == M*(M+1) - N*(N+1)
{
  var a := N;
  s := 0;

  while a < M
    invariant N <= a <= M
    invariant 2*s == a*(a+1) - N*(N+1)
  {
    a := a + 1;
    s := s + a;
  }
}
```

In summary, we have built the loop body from the loop invariant, and we designed this loop invariant by "replacing a constant with a variable" in the postcondition.

Rustan

Comment: nice! I didn't even think of changing the OP's suggested invariant

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate and excellent answer. As a beginner it was extremely helpful to get insight into the thought process of finding invariants (or loop bodies).

Answer (score 1):

You are running afoul of the curse of nonlinear arithmetic. Any time you rely on nontrivial properties of multiplication, Dafny will have a hard time with your program.

Here is one way to fix your specific proof. Sorry that it is so messy. I'm sure it can be cleaned up, but I just hacked something together to show you the idea.

```
function {:opaque} mul(a: int, b: int): int
{
  a * b
}

lemma MulZero1(a: int)
  ensures mul(0, a) == 0
{
  reveal mul();
}

lemma MulNeg1(a: int, b: int)
  ensures mul(-a, b) == -mul(a, b)
{
  reveal mul();
}

lemma MulNeg2(a: int, b: int)
  ensures mul(a, -b) == -mul(a, b)
{
  reveal mul();
}

lemma MulInd(a: nat, b: int)
  ensures mul(a, b) == if a == 0 then 0 else mul(a-1, b) + b
{
  reveal mul();
}

lemma MulEven(a: int, b: int)
  requires b % 2 == 0
  decreases if a < 0 then -a + 1 else a
  ensures mul(a, b) % 2 == 0
{
  if a < 0 {
    MulNeg1(a, b);
    MulEven(-a, b);
  } else if a == 0 {
    MulZero1(b);
  } else {
    calc {
      mul(a, b) % 2;
      { MulInd(a, b); }
      (mul(a-1, b) + b) % 2;
      mul(a-1, b) % 2;
      { MulEven(a-1, b); }
      0;
    }
  }
}

lemma MulComm(a: int, b: int)
  ensures mul(a, b) == mul(b, a)
{
  reveal mul();
}

lemma MulAdjEven(a: int)
  ensures mul(a, a + 1) % 2 == 0
{
  var m := a % 2;

  if m == 0 {
    MulComm(a, a+1);
    MulEven(a+1, a);
  } else {
    assert m == 1;
    assert (a + 1) % 2 == 0;
    MulEven(a, a+1);
  }
}

method doingMath(N: int, M: int) returns (s: int)
requires N <= M //given precondition
ensures 2*s == mul(M,M+1) - mul(N,N+1) //given postcondition
{
    var a: int := N;
    var r: int := 0;

    assert mul(a-N, N) + mul(a-N, (a-N)+1)/2 == 0 by {
      reveal mul();
    }

    while a < M 
      invariant a <= M
      invariant r == mul(a-N, N) + mul(a-N, (a-N)+1)/2
    {
        a := a+1;
        r := r+a;
        assert r == mul(a-N, N) + mul(a-N, (a-N)+1)/2 by {
          reveal mul();
        }
    }

    calc {
      2*r;
      2* (mul(M-N, N) + mul(M-N, (M-N)+1)/2);
      { MulAdjEven(M-N); }
      2*mul(M-N, N) + mul(M-N, (M-N)+1);
      { reveal mul(); }
      mul(M,M+1) - mul(N,N+1);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Multiplication is hard for Dafny, so we manually wrap it in an opaque function. This gives us fine-grained control of when Dafny is allowed to "know" that the function is really multiplication.

Then we can replace all the occurrences of multiplication in your method by calls to `mul`. This makes Dafny fail quickly. (That's a big improvement over timing out!) Then we can selectively reveal the definition of `mul` where we need it, or we can prove lemmas about `mul`.

The hardest lemma is `MulEven`. Try replacing its body/proof by `reveal mul();` and you will see that Dafny times out. Instead, I had to prove it by induction. This proof itself necessitated several other lemmas about multiplication. Fortunately, all of them were easy.

---

You may also want to take a look at the math library developed as part of the IronFleet project [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Ironclad/tree/master/ironfleet/src/Dafny/Libraries/Math). (Start by reading the files whose names contain the word "nonlinear"; those are the lowest-level proofs that are closest to the axioms.) They use a similar approach to build up a large body of facts about multiplication (and division and modulo), so that those functions can remain opaque everywhere else in the codebase, improving Dafny's performance.